# Find duplicates using MySQL considering multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I need to find duplicate uses based on either same `email` **OR** `first_name, last_name` combination **OR** same `birth_date`. What I could comfortably try was:

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name
FROM users
where id IN (SELECT id
             from users
             GROUP BY email
             HAVING count(*) > 1)
GROUP BY email, id;
```

The above gives only duplicate email details, but I'm bit confused about handling other conditions based on `first_name, last_name` combination **OR** same `birth_date` as well.

Is it possible to achieve it in a single query?

Comment: do you want only to see them or you want to delete them ?

Comment: I want to get such duplicate rows and create a csv. But, I'm not sure about the query, including multiple condition check.

Comment: Records 1 and 2 have the same email.  Records 2 and 3 have the same first/last names.  How do you resolve this situation?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yup that's my issue and confusion.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a `UNION` of three separate queries which checks for the three duplicate criteria:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT email) > 1
UNION
(
    SELECT id
    FROM users t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT firstname, lastname
        FROM users
        GROUP BY firstname, lastname
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) t2
        ON t1.firstname = t2.firstname AND
           t1.lastname = t2.lastname
)
UNION
SELECT id
FROM users
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT birthdate) > 1
```

Comment: Well, I hope this works !!! I was also trying with UNION but was struck with **MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION**